# Do I have to analyze change point before using piecewise regression?

Tags: r, matlab, statistics, regression

I have data with change point, do I have to make all change point tests like (chick if there is more than one change point , and residual tests) before I estimate the two linear models using piecewise regression? I want data that fit piecewise regression.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include data and the code you have tried in the question, please.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)